# How to edit multi value selection inputs in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel

working with Laravel 6 and mysql. I have mutiple values input using select2-multi. I have following model structure with Post and Tags Post.php model

```
public function category()
      {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');

      }

      public function tags()
      {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
      }
```

Tag.php Model

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
```

and My PostController edit function is

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $categories = Category::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();
      
        return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($cats)->withTags($tags);
    }
```

and edit blade is

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Tag</label>

   <select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags[]" id="tags" multiple="multiple">
      @foreach($tags as $tag)
           <option value="{{$tag->id}}" @if($tag->id === $post->tag_id) 'selected' @endif >{{$tag->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
   </select>
</div>
```

but when I try to visit edit blade view following error is coming `Undefined variable: tags (View: F:\2020 technologies\laravel\blog\resources\views\posts\edit.blade.php)` 
how could I fix this matter?

Comment: I am not familiar with custom `with` functions, try returning like this `return view('posts.edit')->with('posts',$post)->with('cats',$cats)->with('tags',$tags);`

Comment: return view('posts.edit')->with(compact('posts','cats','tags'));